# Django Count of Items in a Field

Tags: python, django, django-models

models.py

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    distance = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    isnew = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Result(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    score = models.IntegerField()
```

I want to do a query to return a count of each unique Category in the Result table, for a given Event.

What I'm doing now is something like:

```
results = Result.objects.filter(event=myevent)
categorycountdict = {}
for r in results:
    if r.category in categorycountdict:
        categorycountdict[r.category] += 1
    else:
        categorycountdict[r.category] = 1
```

Is there a better way, perhaps by query instead of python.

Comment: In raw SQL you'd want `SELECT category, COUNT(category) FROM result GROUP BY category`, if that helps at all?

Comment: I just realized that you specifically asked for a query, and I guess that is why my answer was downvoted, but this may still be useful to you if you want a more succinct Python solution: `categorycount = len(set([r.category for r in results]))`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `annotate()` with `values()`. This approach is shown in the docs for [`values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#values). To get the count for each category name, you could do:

```
from django.db.models import Count

categories = Result.objects.filter(
    event=myevent,
).order_by('category').values(
    'category__name'
).annotate(count=Count('category__name'))
```

This will return a list of dictionaries with keys `category__name` and `count`, for example:

```
[{'count': 3, 'category__name': u'category1'}, {'count': 1, 'category__name': u'category2'}]
```

You could convert this to a single dictionary by using a dictionary comprehension:

```
counts_by_category = {d['category__name']: d['count'] for f in categories}
```

Comment: All of the dictionaries returned here have count 1 and it repeats categories. I think one dictionary per row of Result.

Comment: You need to order your queryset by category.

Comment: Bingo, thanks! Is there a nice way to turn this list into a single object (dictionary?) that I can query against later in my code to pull the count of a particular one?

Comment: The result is a list of dictionaries, so you can transform it however you like. I've added an extra example to the answer.

Comment: @Alasdair May be you can help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/q/74777154/4956204 similar to this but little bit different wants to merge multiple dictionary with common value.

Comment: @patel887 Sorry I don't spend much time on Stack Overflow any more. Hope you find an answer to you question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Results.objects.filter(event=some_event).annotate(Count('category'), distinct=True)
```

Comment: This counts the number of categories per result, not the number of results per category (as OP as shown) in the given query

Answer (score 1):

There is [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in python standard library:

```
results = Result.objects.filter(event=myevent).select_related('category')
c = Counter(r.category for r in results)
```

Now c is a dict-like object where keys are Category instances, and values are counts.

This option is not suitable for large datasets though, since it doesn't use database features. So if you have a lot of data, approaches that use values, annotate and Count are more suitable.

[select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is used here in order to eliminate database hit for every result. Basically it makes 1 query with join and generates python objects for categories.

---

---

It turns out, that ManyToManyField keeps track of unique records only, so below answer is incorrect.

Your Event and Category models expose many-to-many connection through Result model.

You can express it using [through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) in Django (note categories ManyToManyField):

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True)
    distance = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, through='Result', related_name='events')
```

In your code, for given event you could query like this:

```
event.categories.count()
```

Taking Alasdair note into account:

```
event.categories.values('pk').annotate(count=Count('pk'))
```

Comment: Nice, never knew about [`through`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through). I must remember to use this more..

Comment: `event.categories.count()` will give the total number of categories for that event, not the count of each different category.

Comment: updated answer to take different categories into account

Comment: The OP wants the count for each distinct category, e.g. `{'category1': 5, 'category2': 3}`. Your updated answer still returns a single number.