# Get count as a separate result attribute Django

Tags: python, django, orm, django-rest-framework

I need my code to return count for a specific cam id that is active and i want it to return only once and separately. But it is occurring with every single record. My code is as below for model class:

```
def activeness(self):
        result = MinuteRecords.objects.filter(
            cam_id=self.cam_id,
            face_status='Active',
        ).count()
        return result
```

For my serializer:

```
class MinuteRecordsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    timeago = serializers.DateTimeField(read_only=True)
    activeness = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MinuteRecords
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('timeago',)
```

The result that i get is

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "timeago": "5 days, 21 hours",
        "activeness": 2,
        "cam_id": 1,
        "timestamp": "2020-02-06T14:55:26.852392Z",
        "face_status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "timeago": "1 week",
        "activeness": 2,
        "cam_id": 1,
        "timestamp": "2020-02-04T15:17:34.590323Z",
        "face_status": "Active"
    }
]
```

The result that i expect is :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "timeago": "5 days, 21 hours",
        "cam_id": 1,
        "timestamp": "2020-02-06T14:55:26.852392Z",
        "face_status": "Active"
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "timeago": "1 week",
        "cam_id": 1,
        "timestamp": "2020-02-04T15:17:34.590323Z",
        "face_status": "Active"
    },
        "activeness": 2,
]
```

The crux being that i want to return the total number of records after my query as a separate record rather than being appended with every result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django Count of Items in a Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39513627/django-count-of-items-in-a-field)

Comment: That person asked the count for each individual category. Where as in my case I just want the count of the cam id that i have entered in the filter clause and then return it as a separate record as i have shown in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by overriding `finalize_response` method of your ViewSet.

```
def finalize_response(self, request, response, *args, **kwargs):

     response_received = super().finalize_response(request, response, *args, **kwargs)
     if len(response_received.data) > 0:
        activeness = response_received.data[0].pop('activeness', None)
        for minute_data in response_received.data:
            minute_data.pop('activeness', None)

     response_received.data.append({'activeness': activeness} 


     return response_received
```

What you are doing here is that you are customizing the response as per your requirements after fetching the records from DB.

Hope this helps.